# After opening a mdb in a working copy

Tags: tortoisesvn

Hallo all,

In my institute, Tortoise is employed for the purpose of version control.

I find, if a mdb file which belongs to the working copy of a project reporitory is opened thru Access, the ordinary will be labelled with an explamation mark. Since the database has not been modified, I don't unterstand why Tortoise regards the opening as a kind of modification. How could I get back the tick label afte closing the mdb file without any changes?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening an Access database (mdb) will instantly create modifications of the file, even if there are no actual changes made. The MS Jet Database Engine which you use when working with mdb files saves temp data right inside the mdb file which causes the file to change regardless of changes to the data itself.

Tortoise is technically doing the right thing when marking the mdb as changed.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. 
How could I get back the tick label afte closing the mdb file without any changes?

Comment: use 'revert' on that file. That will discard any changes made.